# How do I make an optional action for an Octane component?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-3, ember-octane

I want to write an Octane/Glimmer style component where passing in the action is optional. What is the best way to write this?

For example, I want both of these uses of the component to be valid:

```
<MyComponent />
<MyComponent @validate={{action this.validate}} />
```

Right now, my component class has a lot of code that looks like this, checking to see if an action was passed in before calling it:

```js
if (this.args.validate) {
  this.args.validate()
}
```

That works fine for one action, but not if I need to call several optional methods in succession. What other options are there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several options available to make this optional actions code neater - use a getter, use `tryInvoke`, use a helper, or write a decorator.

Using a getter is vanilla JavaScript and may be easiest for others reading the code to understand:

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  get validate() {
    return this.args.validate || function() {};
  }

  @action
  someOtherAction() {
    this.validate()
  }
}
```

[`tryInvoke`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.14/functions/@ember%2Futils/tryInvoke) is an Ember API method that checks if a function exists before calling it. The drawbacks are that when other people are searching the code for uses of the function, their search may not find it:

```js
tryInvoke(this.args, 'validate');
```

You could install or create your own `optional` helper. The [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#optional) addon has an `optional` helper. Use it like this in a template.

```
{{action (optional @validate) someArg}}
```

Finally, you could possibly write your own decorator and call it something like `@argumentFallback`, then use it to label the defaults your component should use if no arguments are provided to the component.

Thanks to bendemboski and theroncross for the information!